# Are any upgrade options permanent like in wings of liberty?

Tags: starcraft-2

I am concerned about my choices for leveling up in the Heart of the Swarm campaign because in Wings of Liberty I made some bad choices which I could not reverse.

I notice the Evolution Chamber upgrades can be changed on the fly for zerglings, but are there upgrades which can't changed such as Kerrigans levels?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only "permanent" choices are the results of the "Evolution Missions". (For an example, see here: [Raptor or Swarmling Zerglings in HOTS?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108449/raptor-or-swarmling-zerglings-in-hots) )

The 'smaller' evolved benefits, available directly from the evolution pit (once you unlock the unit) may be changed at any time, as can Kerrigan powers.

The zergling lemon juice allergy, however, you're stuck with.

Comment: Wow, that is a hard decision. Here i was thinking that I would have it easy and could swap!